# In raspberrypi 3v3 pin output is not providing power

Tags: pi-3, gpio, sd-card

i am working with raspberry pi suddenly my terminal got stuck and after i dis-connect my raspberrypi and again connect it ;but it not detect my raspberrypi sd card and i found that 3v3 pin is not providing any output and check with multimeter it show 0v,but in 5v pin i got 5v. I also see this kind of problem in my office,3 raspberrypi devices fail in that way.Anybody told me how to rectify this problem.
is my device can able to repair?

Comment: How were you powering your Pi? What did you have connected to it?

Answer (score 5):

It is not economical to attempt a repair.  It will be cheaper to buy a new Pi.

If the 3V3 power circuitry is broken it might have caused further problems downstream.  The SoC may have been destroyed.